# Ошибка zincrby() got multiple values for argument 'amount'

Tags: python, django, redis

```
r.zincrby(name=self.get_product_key(product_id),
                          amount=1,
                          value=with_id)
```

Выходит ошибка, что amount получила несколько значений. Как оно может получить несколько значений если все значения я передаю по их именам.
Код самой функции zincrby:

```
def zincrby(self, name, amount, value):
    "Increment the score of ``value`` in sorted set ``name`` by ``amount``"
    return self.execute_command('ZINCRBY', name, amount, value)
```

Comment: Вы передаете в функцию именованные аргументы. я принимаете неименованные. Попробуйте так, чтоли: `r.zincrby(self.get_product_key(product_id), 1, with_id)`

Comment: @strawdog Нет не помогло. Я не знаю в чем проблема я же передаю 3 аргумента там тоже 3 все по порядку